# Dynamically remove a part of the word

Tags: python, pandas

I have words which are made up of two parts `x` and `y` where `x` can take many values & `y` can be either be blank or can take fixed number of values.

x is like: `Apple, Banana, Mango, .... many more`

y is like: `Buy, Sell, Good`

Words are: `AppleBuy, BananaGood, Mango, MangoSell`

**Input df**

```
Name
AppleBuy
BananaGood
Mango
MangoSell
Apple Buy
```

**Expected DF**

```
Name
Apple
Banana
Mango
Mango
Apple
```

**Code:**

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('AppleBuy','Apple').str.replace('BananaGood','Banana')
```

**Problem**

The above code works fine but the problem is if tomorrow a new x comes then the above code fails.

Can I have something dynamic which gets the expected output irrespective of value of x.

Comment: Is regex an option for this problem?

Comment: Values `x` or `y` should be extracted?

Comment: Are the first letters of x and y always capitals?

Comment: In what way does the code "fail"?

Comment: It works, but if tomorrow if something new comes, it wont be able to handle say `CherryBuy` has to be converted to `Cherry`. The above will fail, so need something dynamic. The accepted answer does so!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) or [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
y = ['Buy','Sell','Good']
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('|'.join(y), '').str.strip()
print (df)
     Name
0   Apple
1  Banana
2   Mango
3   Mango
```

Or:

```
x = ['Apple','Banana','Mango']
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(x) + ')', expand=False)

print (df)
     Name
0   Apple
1  Banana
2   Mango
3   Mango
```

If want values with uppercase separator:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.extract('([A-Z][a-z]*)')

print (df)
     Name
0   Apple
1  Banana
2   Mango
3   Mango
```

Comment: I have not included this in my above example: But can the answer also handle something like `Apple Buy` becomes `Apple`

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - second solution working, for first is necessary add `.str.strip()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.extract('([A-Z].*?\w+(?=[A-Z]){2})').str.strip().fillna(df['Name'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Name
0   Apple
1  Banana
2   Mango
3   Mango
```

Comment: I have not included this in my above example: But can the answer also handle something like `Apple Buy` becomes `Apple`

Answer (score 0):

```
list_X = ['AppleBuy', 'BananaGood', 'Mango', 'MangoSell']
list_Y = ['Buy', 'Sell', 'Good']

for index, x in enumerate(list_X):
    for y in list_Y:
        if x.lower().endswith(y.lower()):
            list_X[index] = x.replace(y, '')

print(list_X)
['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Mango']
```

Comment: My x is dynamic, I have not sure how many are there. So, everytime I need to change the x value to my code

Answer (score 0):

If regex is an option you can use something like this:

```
[re.search('^[A-Z][a-z]*', i)[0] for i in df['name']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "Apple, Banana, Mango, Good"
y = "Buy, Sell, Good"
print(set((i.strip() for i in x.split(',') if len(i.strip())>0)) - set((i.strip() for i in y.split(',') if len(i.strip())>0)))
```

unordered set.

Comment: My x is dynamic, I have not sure how many are there. So, everytime I need to change the x value to my code